# Serialization of enum fails

Tags: c#, enums, xml-serialization

I use .NET 3.5 for this.

I have an enum:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum MyEnum
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("035")]
    Item1,
    Item2
}
```

I use this enum in a class:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to create a new Eplomyee-instance, set the MyEnum-property by casting it from a string.
Then serialize it and save it in a file.

```
Employee bob = new Employee() {Id = 1, Name = "Bob"};
bob.MyEnum = (MijnEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "035"));

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Employee));
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\myfile.xml");
using (FileStream stream = fi.OpenWrite())
{
    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, bob); // this is place where it goes wrong
    }
}
```

If I debug this, I see that the value of `bob.MyEnum` is **35**

When I try to serialize, I get an exception:

> There was an error generating the XML document.
>
> Instance validation error: '35' is not a valid value for
>   WindowsFormsApplication.MyEnum.

What is going wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: You are doing it very wrong. Specifically `Enum.Parse`.

Comment: Have you tried to assign: `Item1 = 25,` in the enum declaration?

Comment: You know you can just use [Serializable] instead of [System.SerializableAttribute()]?

Comment: @leppie: enlighten me. Perhaps this can solve my problem.

Comment: @Botz3000: yes, I know that. The attribute was auto-generated, hence the full name...

Comment: @Erno: I did now and that seems to work. Thanx. But I hope to find a solution that does not involve adapting the enum.

Comment: why you have to read it from a string?

Comment: `XmlSerialization` is an apple. `Enum.Parse` is a pear.

Comment: @onof: because my input is a string. I can't change that.

Comment: @leppie: thanks for tweeting my question...

Comment: @Natrium: I never complained about the question on twitter, but rather the answers given at that stage.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because, `Enums` are internally store as `int`. Hence your statement `bob.MyEnum = (MijnEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "035"));` is running without issue. If you debug, value of `bob.MyEnum` is `35`. When you deserialize this, deserializer searches for matching `enum` with int value 35, which is not there, as you are specifying Item1 and Item2. Hence you get an error.

This will work

```
 bob.MyEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "35");

 public enum MyEnum {
   Item1 = 35,
   Item2
 }
```

Ideally you should be doing this

```
 bob.MyEnum = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "Single");

 public enum MyEnum {
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Single")]
   Item1,
   Item2
 }
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: As in, i didn't get you. I didn't give any solution. I explained why it happend.

Comment: @leppie the user's input is a string. And i think you're comments here are a bit rude or offensive. IMO your reputation doesn't give you this privilege.

Comment: @onof: Sorry, if I am trying to point out the incorrectiveness of these answers, due to simple reasons like not reading a question and understanding the problem. I have now posted an answer. I didn't think it was needed, but it seems I was mistaken.

Comment: While I was a bit surprised that snippet 1 works (you get your downvote back ;p), the second snippet still does not work or do anything the OP has not tried.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()] // useless, valuetype is implicitly so
public enum MyEnum
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("035")]
    Item1,
    Item2
}
```

Now the `XmlEnumAttribute` controls how that value is serialized and deserialized in XML.

**IT HAS NOTHING TO WITH THE REST OF YOUR CODE!** (sorry for the caps, but no-one else seems to get this).

So when a value of `MyEnum.Item1` get serialized, "035" will be emitted.

Now the problem is how you want to assign this.

It is simple. Just assign like you would normally do. None these attributes change semantics of normal code, everything stays the same.

Example:

```
Employee bob = new Employee() {Id = 1, Name = "Bob", MyEnum = MyEnum.Item1};
```

There is abolutely no reason why `Enum.Parse` should even be considered here. The enum type and value is statically known.

If you did want to use `Enum.Parse`, use it like normal, example:

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "Item1")
```

Comment: I have to parse the string to enum. Ok, I hardcoded "035" here in my example. But in my program, it comes from a variable.

Comment: @Natrium: If it is a variable, just assign it! You are doing things in a very complex and unneeded way.

Comment: @Natrium: What does not work? Show me, I can't really tell what you are attempting to do any more.

Comment: @Natrium: I am still waiting (and trying and willing) to help you. Please explain where what goes wrong.

Comment: @leppie at the end you are also doing same thing. I think you need to consider that downvote. You can parse `Enum` in only two ways, `Enum.Parse` or `Enum.TryParse` from string. If there is any other way, you can mention it.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure: No, I only showed that to show to use that function properly. Read my answer, and you will see it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the enum-parsing.

I used reflection to parse the string to the enum, as described in this article: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/enumerations/article.php/c5869

And now it works.

Comment: While I agree the above should work, it seems needlessly complex for a simple task.

Comment: Do you know how this is different than Enum.Parse?